# Bit-timing not yet defined for mcp2515

Tags: raspberry-pi4, can-bus

i'm trying to set up my mcp2515 with a VP230 Can transceiver for can communication.
so far, i am able to connect the mcp to my rpi using SPI bus 0, and to set it up as can0 in rpi.
However when i tried to set the communication up, it seems like it was set up when i run the command
"ip -d -s link show can0"
however when i run the command
"dmesg | fgrep -i can"
it shows that the can bit-timing is not yet defined.

I'm pretty new to rpi and can devices, so any advice would definitely help!
Thanks

Able to establish bit timing for MCP2515 spi bus.

[image: message on linux]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit the /boot/config.txt file from

> dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0,interrupt=25,oscillator=8000000

to

> dtoverlay=mcp2515,spi0-0,interrupt=25,oscillator=8000000

It seems like its due the kernel version change.
Source of information is from another forum
[link](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils/issues/359#issuecomment-1119666048)